# How to set AWS EBS Volume Snapshot deletion Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

Few of my critical EBS Volumes are being backed up as snapshots periodically. Is there any way I can setup a deletion policy by which ONLY the recent two snapshots are maintained?

For example:
In one of the environment I have close to 300 snapshots from 10 EBS Volumes. Once I have this policy it should come down to 20 Snapshot and be maintained at that level.

Comment: EBS does not, as of now, have a built-in mechanism to automatically trigger deletion of snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that snapshots ALL EBS volumes, then only keeps the latest 2 snapshots. You could also modify it to only snapshot volumes with a particular tag. Substitute your own Region as appropriate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2, os

MAX_SNAPSHOTS = 2   # Number of snapshots to keep

# Connect to EC2 in this region
connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of all volumes
volumes = connection.get_all_volumes()

# Create a snapshot of each volume
for v in volumes:
  connection.create_snapshot(v.id)

  # Too many snapshots?
  snapshots = v.snapshots()
  if len(snapshots) > MAX_SNAPSHOTS:

    # Delete oldest snapshots, but keep MAX_SNAPSHOTS available
    snap_sorted = sorted([(s.id, s.start_time) for s in snapshots], key=lambda k: k[1])
    for s in snap_sorted[:-MAX_SNAPSHOTS]:
      print "Deleting snapshot", s[0]
      connection.delete_snapshot(s[0])
```

Just run it as a daily `cron` job.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid-2018, this can now be automated using the [Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html). You set up the rules such as how often to take a snapshot and how many to retain (or for how long) and it does the rest. (The difference between how many to retain versus for how long comes into play after you stop taking snapshots.)

I know that in general Stack Overflow frowns on answers that are just links, but while it is conceptually simple, there are too many pieces to explain for me to fully document it here. Please refer to the official AWS documentation.